# Get day of the week for last 7 days?

Tags: php, date

I need the names of the day (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thuesday, Friday, Saturday, Today).

I know this is a newby question and PHP has a `date()` function. But I tried and can't figure out how...

Comment: How exactly do you want the days? What's your input here?

Comment: Input is from today. If that makes any sense?

Comment: what logic is there, please explain that.

Comment: Just add these to an array..! Use `date()` when you've some actual date input... Like, what day is 10th June 2014! That's when you use `date()`

Comment: Ok, I just need the names of the last 7 days starting from what ever date "today" is. Output should be like mentioned above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create array of a week days name in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536748/how-to-create-array-of-a-week-days-name-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Achieving this using the `DateTime` Class and its `format` method.

The below code's output changes every day.. Since today is **Sunday** it starts from Monday , Tuesday... If you run this code on **Tuesday** , you will be getting output as Thursday , Friday , Saturday .. so on.

```
<?php

for($i=1;$i<=7;$i++) //<--- Since we know total days in a week is 7.
{
    $date = new DateTime(); //<-- Grabs today's datetime
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P'.$i.'D')); //<--- Passes the current value of $i to add days..
    echo $date->format('l')."<br>";
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/125209)

Answer (score 0):

According to the PHP Manual at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php, just use "l" as the format parameter to get the full name of the day.

So 23rd Mar 2014 is a Sunday, as echoed by

```
<?php
echo date ("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, 3, 23, 2014));
// Echoes Sunday
?>
```

To get past 7, 6, 5 or 10000 days (or number of days in the future) from the current day, according the information at [this page](http://notrelated.com/2010/02/28/getting-yesterday-last-week-last-month-or-last-year-in-php/), just use negative or positive integers in a string in the strtotime function:

```
<?php
$backcount = -4;
echo date ("l", strtotime("$backcount day"));
// Executed on 23 Mar 2014 will give Wednesday
?>
```

Knowing this, you can apply a *for* loop to get what you need. And if want "Today" instead of the full name of the current day, just add an *if* condition to handle the situation where the backcount variable is zero.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jddayofweek](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.jddayofweek.php) to retrieve day of week, it has 3 mode for string containing the day of week, string containing the abbreviated day of week and int represent number of day in week

```
for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
    $x=jddayofweek($i,2);
    var_dump($x);
}
```