# particular week days with repeat occurrences php

Tags: php

Repeat every Tuesday of the week
    Repeat every Saturday of the week. based on the occurrences

example:

```
5 recurrence means , the event will repeat 5times like 
tuesday , saturday, tuesday, saturday, tuesday
```

my code is

`$ron` is the user selected weekdays `1=monday`, `2=tuesday` etc.

```
 $ron="1,5,3";
 $ronS=explode(',', $ron);
 foreach($ronS as $ronS) {
   $res[]= $ronS;
 }
 $s ="09-05-2014 00:00:00";
 $ii=0;
 $m= date("M",strtotime($s));
 $curday= 7-date("N",strtotime($s));
 foreach($res as $key=>$val) 
 {
      $week = array('0'=>"Sunday","1"=>"Monday","2"=>"Tuesday","3"=>"Wednesday","4"=>"Thursday","5"=>"Friday","6"=>"Saturday");
      $day[] = $week[$val]."-";
      $ncount= $res[$key];
      if($ii==0)
      {
          $nc=$ncount+$curday;
          $cday= date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+'.$nc.' day',strtotime($s)));
          // echo $st=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('Next '.$day));
          $ii++;
      } 
      else
      {
          $nc=$ncount+$curday;
          $cday= date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+'.$nc.' day',strtotime($s)));
          $ii++;
      }
      $datetime = new DateTime("$cday");
      if ( $datetime->format("w") >= 0 )
      {
         echo "\n $cday is ".$datetime->format("l")."\n";
      }
   }
```

The output of this code is:

```
2014-05-12 00:00:00 is Monday

2014-05-16 00:00:00 is Friday

2014-05-14 00:00:00 is Wednesday
```

If user input is `$ron="1,2,3"` and the occurrences is 5 ,occurrences means how many times the days will repeat.

Example o/p:

```
$ron="1,3";
$occurances=5 
$s ="09-05-2014 00:00:00";
```

o/p will be

```
2014-05-12 00:00:00 is Monday

 2014-05-14 00:00:00 is Wednesday

 2014-05-19 00:00:00 is Monday

 2014-05-21 00:00:00 is Wednesday

 2014-05-26 00:00:00 is Monday
```

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried? You must have SOME code. This seems a bit lazy.

Comment: Please share your code here which you have tried..